# How to add options in grapesjs framework

Tags: javascript

I dont know how to add the options. from my code I am getting an error. Unexpected token in 'gjs-blocks-basic': {'block'}

My code:

```js
var editor = grapesjs.init({
        height: '100%',
        noticeOnUnload: 0,
        storageManager:{autoload: 0},
        container : '#gjs',
        fromElement: true,
        plugins: ['gjs-blocks-basic'],
        pluginsOpts: {
          'gjs-blocks-basic': {'block'}
        }
      });
```

The list of options:

[Options that are available to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPQaa.png)

Usage of the code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var editor = grapesjs.init({
      fromElement: 1,
      container : '#gjs',
      plugins: ['gjs-blocks-basic'],
      pluginsOpts: {
        'gjs-blocks-basic': {/* ...options */}
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
      plugins: ['my-plugin-name'],
      pluginsOpts: {
        'my-plugin-name': {
          customField: 'customValue'
        }
      }
```

Got it working.Here is the syntax for adding options.